# Is it possible that KDE applications running under Gnome can use the information of Gnome applications?

Tags: gnome, kde, gui

I am running Okular on Ubuntu. When I try to save a copy of a pdf file I edited in Okular back to the same directory, I can't access the "Recent" and "bookmark" information of Nautilus. This is unlike in Evince, where I can always access the above information of Nautilus from Evince. So I wonder if it is possible that KDE applications, when running under Gnome, can use the information from applications based on Gnome? Thanks!

Comment: Same problem with other KDE applications running under Gnome.

Comment: @sim: thanks! Not the question you asked me to ask.

Comment: @slm Point taken.

Comment: @Tim - yup not a problem, but your Q is fine here.